# How to find only categories variables?

Tags: r

This code snippet takes the data set `train` and tries to print it if its variables are not categories. I am finding that `is.factor(varname[i])` is always `FALSE`. How to rectify it?

```
find_Cat <- function(){
  varname<-NULL
  for(i in  1 : length(names(train))){   
    varname[i]<-paste('train$',names(train)[i],sep='')
    if(is.factor(varname[i])) 
    print("This is Category variable ")    
  }
}
```

Comment: How about just `sapply(iris, is.factor)`

Comment: [moved to discussion of the question instead of dicussion of answer). Are you sure you only want factors? What exactly do you mean by 'category variable'? If a variable is of class 'character', it's often considered categorical as well.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `lapply`

```
lapply(train, function(x) if(is.factor(x))
                   'This is Category variable'
                   else NULL)
```

Comment: Depends on the format of the data, but technically variables that are only 0 or 1, or different strings are also categorical but not always a factor.

Comment: Thanks but  what is the problem with my code ?Because  I want to get the mode of all those categories variables instead of printing "This is Category   variable' as further purpose of code.

Comment: @AjitTramp `sapply(train, class)` gets the class of each of the variables.

Answer (score 1):

Or if you want a character vector in return, you can slightly alter akrun's code.

```
factors <- vapply(train, 
            function(x) if (is.factor(x)) 
                         "This is a Category Variable" 
                         else "", 
            character(1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `Filter` for this if you like:

Using the built-in `iris` data set:

```
names(Filter(is.factor, iris))
[1] "Species"
```

`Filter` will extract the columns that are factors and `names` returns the names of the factor columns.

---

Based on your comment, if you want to find the mode of all categorical columns you could do:

```
df <- data.frame(a=runif(5), b=rep(c('a','b'), c(2,3)), c=rep(c('a','d'), c(2,3)) )

#> df
#           a b c
#1 0.29489199 a a
#2 0.08649974 a a
#3 0.65941729 b d
#4 0.49732569 b d
#5 0.62138883 b d


#the below will find the mode of the column whether it is factor or character 
#assuming you have numeric, integer, character and factor columns
lapply(Filter(Negate(is.numeric), df),
       function(x) names(sort(table(x), decreasing=TRUE)[1]))

$b
[1] "b"

$c
[1] "d"
```

Comment: Thanks @LyzandeR but the larger question is why my code snippet is not giving the right answer.

Comment: `varname[i]<-paste('train$',names(train)[i],sep='')` always creates a string. In other words this is only a character string and not the variable that contains the data you need to check. You could use `varname[i] <- train[, i]` instead which is the proper way to get the column with the variables.

Comment: However, `for-loops` are not very efficient in R so you should probably learn how to use the above techniques which are the usual way of tackling such problems.